# find the expectation and the variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The diameter of sand grains in a special sand roof, measured in mm, can be considered as a random variable X with probability density
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
k(x-x^2) & \text{if 0≤x≤1 }  \\
\newline 0 &\text{otherwhise}
\end{cases}$$

A)
Determine the constant k so that this becomes a valid probability density

$1=k\int _0^1x-x^2dx$

$k=6 $

B)Find the expectation $E (4X + 3)$ and the variance $V (4X + 3)$

I should be able to find the expectation and the variance, but what do I do now?

$\int _0^1\left(6\left(x-x^2\right)\right)\: = 1$

Is this the way?

$$\mathsf E(4X+3) = 4\mathsf E(X)+3\\\mathsf{Var}(4X+3)=4^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$$

any tips/solutions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The hint was

$E(4X+3)=4E(X)+3$

and

$V(4X+3)=16V(X)$

thus calulate expectation and variance of your rv X with the definitions

$$E(X)=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$V(X)=\int_0^1 x^2f(x)dx-E^2(X)=\frac{3}{10}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}$$

then apply what suggested.

Comment: $E^2(X)$ is the same as  $(E(X))^2$

Comment: @Papps : yes, it is the mean^2

Comment: and to find $16V$ do I just multiply with $16$ at in the end for $V(X)$. And multiply with $4$ and plus with $3$ at the end of  $4E(X)+3$

Comment: @Papps The first sentence is right. You multiply the variance $V(X)$ by $16$ which is $V(4X+3)=\frac45$. You´re done. The second sentence is unnecessary.

Comment: @callculus Why would it be unnecessary? did they not ask for 4E(X)+3?

Comment: @Papps I was referring to $V(4X+3)$ and not to $\mathbb E(4X+3)$